# C++: When using nested arrays, regardless of how I implement, the inner or outer loop doesn't work

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is get lines from a file then adjust them and write those adjusted lines to a temporary file. Then write the adjusted lines from the temporary file to the initial file and doing so for a number of times. The initial loop is the rounds the adjustments have to occur and there are basically two inner loops. One is to get lines from initial file adjust them then write them to temp file and the second is the one that gets the adjusted lines from the temp file and writes them to the initial file.

What is happening is that the code goes through the first loop once completes the two inner loops fine but then doesn't continue through anymore outer loops, so one round even if there's many.

I tried using for loops and am now using while loops but regardless for some reason either inner or outer doesn't work right. I'm new to using ifstreams and ofstreams so I'm sure my code isn't the greatest. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// WriteToFile.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    ofstream writePlayersInfo("PlayerInfo.txt");
    ifstream getPlayersInfo("PlayerInfo.txt");
    ofstream writeTempFile("tempFile.txt");
    ifstream getTempFile("tempFile.txt");

    int numPlayers;
    int rounds;
    vector <string> players;
    players.push_back("empty");
    string player;
    string switchScore;
    int score;
    regex reg("\\s(\\d*)");
    smatch match;

    cout << "How many players are there?\n";
    cin >> numPlayers;
    cout << "Enter the name of each player?\n";
    for (int x = 1; x <= numPlayers; x++)
    {
        cin >> player;
        players.push_back(player);
        writePlayersInfo << player << " 0\n";
    }
    cout << "How many rounds are being played?\n";
    cin >> rounds;
    writePlayersInfo.seekp(0);
    int y = 1;
    while (y <= rounds)
    {
        int z = 1;
        while (getline(getPlayersInfo, switchScore))
        {
            cout << "Enter " << players[z] << "'s score for round " << y << ":\n";
            cin >> score;
            regex_search(switchScore, match, reg);
            score += stoi(match.str());
            switchScore = regex_replace(switchScore, reg, " " + to_string(score) + "\n");
            writeTempFile << switchScore;
            z += 1;
        }
        writePlayersInfo.seekp(0);
        getPlayersInfo.seekg(0);
        writeTempFile.seekp(0);
        getTempFile.seekg(0);
        while (getline(getTempFile, switchScore))
        {
            writePlayersInfo << switchScore << "\n";
        }
        writePlayersInfo.seekp(0);
        getPlayersInfo.seekg(0);
        writeTempFile.seekp(0);
        getTempFile.seekg(0);
        y += 1;
    }

    writePlayersInfo.close();
    getPlayersInfo.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better describe, \*what\* you want to achieve ... not \*how\* you think that can be done. I don't see any point in that reading, writing, reading, writing to files.

Comment: @Swordfish I need to incorporate at least one file where I am writing and reading from, it's for homework. What I am trying to achieve is that a user will be asked for the number of rounds, number of players and names of each player. Then for each round each user enters their score for that round. That score should then be added to their overall score within the file.